# How to wrap the text in the Header field of a ToggleSwitch in UWP

Tags: uwp, responsive, togglebutton, word-wrap

I have a ToggleSwitch on the settings page of a UWP app, and I noticed that the Header text for the ToggleSwitch does not have a way to wrap it. When I test the app in the phone emulator, the Header goes right off the page. Any idea how I could make the text wrap like you can with a TextBlock?

```
<StackPanel Margin="10,0">
    <ToggleSwitch Name="toggleOne" Header="Check this on if you want the app to automatically trigger the zombie apocalypse" Margin="10" />
    <ToggleSwitch Name="toggleTwo" Header="Short Sample Text" Margin="10" />
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add a `HeaderTemplate` for the ToggleSwitch like this:

```
        <ToggleSwitch
            Name="toggleOne"
            Margin="10"
            Header="Check this on if you want the app to automatically trigger the zombie apocalypse">
            <ToggleSwitch.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ToggleSwitch.HeaderTemplate>
        </ToggleSwitch>
```